# Using AutoMapper in a model's constructor in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've recently been updating an old ASP .NET MVC project to ASP .NET Core 6 and have been updating my AutoMapper reconfiguration across the site. Before the update, I used Automapper to initially map the model in it's constructor.

```
public HWAssetDetailsViewModel(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork, string id)
        {
            var hw = _unitOfWork.hwAsset.AllEager().FirstOrDefault(h => h.HWID.ToLower() == id.ToLower());
            if (hw != null)
            {
                Mapper.Map<HWAsset, HWAssetDetailsViewModel>(hw, this);

                this.Manufacturer = hw.HWModel.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName;

                if(hw.ParentHW_ID != null) ParentHWID = _unitOfWork.hwAsset.Find(hw.ParentHW_ID).HWID;
            }
        }
```

My problem now is I can't figure out how to get the new way of calling mapper to work with `this` to automatically map it to the model parameters. I feel like I might be missing something simple here with constructor, but I would like to not have to refactor all of my code to not use Automapper because I have a lot of instances like this.

```
public HWAssetDetailsViewModel(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork, IMapper _mapper, string id)
        {
            var hw = _unitOfWork.hwAsset.AllEager().FirstOrDefault(h => h.HWID.ToLower() == id.ToLower());
            if (hw != null)
            {
                //error thrown for both of these
                _mapper.Map<HWAssetDetailsViewModel>(hw, this);
                this = _mapper.Map<HWAssetDetailsViewModel>(hw);

                this.Manufacturer = hw.HWModel.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName;

                if(hw.ParentHW_ID != null) ParentHWID = _unitOfWork.hwAsset.Find(hw.ParentHW_ID).HWID;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is just one way of many, but this works quite good for me.

In your Program.cs / Startup.cs you'll need to add `AutoMapper` to the service collection.

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(ProfileFactory.CustomProfiles);
// ...
```

The `ProfileFactory`:

```cs
public static class ProfileFactory
{
    private static readonly Type[] s_profiles = new[] {
        typeof(FooProfile),
        typeof(BarProfile)
    };

    public static Type[] CustomProfiles => s_profiles;
}
```

The `FooProfile`:

```cs
using AutoMapper;

public class FooProfile : Profile
{
    public FooProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, FooReadDto>();
        CreateMap<FooCreateDto, Foo>();
        CreateMap<FooUpdateDto, Foo>();
        CreateMap<Foo, FooUpdateDto>();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can call either

```cs
var fooDto = _mapper.Map<FooReadDto>(fooSource);
```

or

```cs
_mapper.Map(fooSource, fooDestination);
```

or even

```cs
var fooDto = _mapper.Map<Foo, FooReadDto>(fooSource);
```

Comment: I had already created the mappings in a separate file, but the second _mapper call was just what I needed! I was just incorrectly doing a call, so mapping it with _mapper.Map(hw, this) worked for me